# Swift 2 Game Main Menu

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift2

I am trying to implement a main menu to my Spritekit game, but whenever I try to present the scene I get a blank gray screen. Here is the code right now, which presents the game itself and not a menu:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {

        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true
        skView.showsDrawCount = true

        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
        skView.presentScene(scene)

    }
}
```

I'm new to this, and I wasn't sure what to do so I tried replacing GameScene with the menu scene, which gave me the gray screen. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you created a MenuScene? did you create it in the Scene editor or code only?

Comment: @RonMyschuk yep, I made my MenuScene in code only.

Comment: the above code loads a scene from an .SKS file which is edited in the scene editor. I will post some code to load a file that is created in code only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to load a SKScene file that is created in code only and not in the Scene editor

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {

    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    if let skView = self.view as? SKView {

        if skView.scene == nil {

            let scene = MenuScene(size: skView.bounds.size)

            skView.showsFPS = false
            skView.showsNodeCount = true
            skView.showsPhysics = true
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }
}
```

and then in your MenuScene file you will need an init func

```
init(size: CGSize) {

    super.init(size: size)

    name = "menuScene"
}
```